# numpy - ndarray - how to remove rows based on another array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to remove rows from a ndarray based on another array.
for example:

```
k = [1,3,99]

n = [
  [1,'a']
  [2,'b']
  [3,'c']
  [4,'c']
  [.....]
  [99, 'a']
  [100,'e']
]
```

expect result:

```
out = [
  [2,'b']
  [4,'c']
  [.....]
  [100,'e']
]
```

the first column of the rows with the values in k will be removed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to create a mask of matches between the first column of `n`  and `k` and then use the inverted mask to select the non-matching rows off `n`, like so  -

```
n[~np.in1d(n[:,0].astype(int), k)]
```

If the first column is already of `int` dtype, skip the `.astype(int)` conversion step.

Sample run -

```
In [41]: n
Out[41]: 
array([['1', 'a'],
       ['2', 'b'],
       ['3', 'c'],
       ['4', 'c'],
       ['99', 'a'],
       ['100', 'e']], 
      dtype='|S21')

In [42]: k
Out[42]: [1, 3, 99]

In [43]: n[~np.in1d(n[:,0].astype(int), k)]
Out[43]: 
array([['2', 'b'],
       ['4', 'c'],
       ['100', 'e']], 
      dtype='|S21')
```

For peformance, if the first column is sorted, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
mask = np.ones(n.shape[0],dtype=bool)
mask[np.searchsorted(n[:,0], k)] = 0
out = n[mask]
```

Comment: the searchsorted solution just removed the first matched element of k, other two rows are not removed

Comment: @Wenhui Is the first column of `n` sorted? If it is, try with `mask[np.searchsorted(n[:,0].astype(int), k)] = 0`.

Comment: @Wenhui Did that answer your query?

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is list, please find simple solution as below, however you can convert into list by list() method.

```
def check(list):
 k=[1,3,99]
 if(list[0] not in k): 
  return list

final_list = map(check,n)
final_list = final_list.remove(None)
print final_list
```